# AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith' -- WindowsPath is correct and contains files that endswith .tif

Tags: python

I'm stuck at the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Here is a part of the code:

```py
im_path = Path("C:/Users/zeiss/_Python/fastddm-main/tests/test-imgs/confocal/")
images = np.array([fddm.tiff2numpy(im) for im in sorted(im_path.iterdir()) if im.name.endswith(".tif")])
images = np.ascontiguousarray(images)
images.shape
```

And the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 3
      1 # read image files
      2 im_path = Path("C:/Users/zeiss/_Python/fastddm-main/tests/test-imgs/confocal/")
----> 3 images = np.array([fddm.tiff2numpy(im) for im in sorted(im_path.iterdir()) if im.name.endswith(".tif")])
      4 images = np.ascontiguousarray(images)
      5 images.shape

File c:\Users\zeiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\fastddm\_utils.py:60, in tiff2numpy(src, seq, color_seq, input_order)
     23 def tiff2numpy(
     24     src: str,
     25     seq: Optional[Sequence[int]] = None,
     26     color_seq: Optional[Sequence[int]] = None,
     27     input_order: Optional[str] = None,
     28 ) -> np.ndarray:
     29     """Read a TIFF file (or a sequence inside a multipage TIFF) and return it as a numpy array.
     30 
     31     The tiff file is assumed to be of the shape (T,Y,X). If `color_seq` is given, the order
   (...)
     58         Coordinate convention is (T,Y,X) (or (C,T,Y,X)).
     59     """
---> 60     if not src.endswith(".tif"):  # read anything but tif files with io.imread
     61         warnings.warn(
     62             "Non-tiff file, returning array opened with default settings only."
     63         )
     64         return io.imread(src)

AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Can someone offer advice on what might be causing this? Thanks!

I confirmed that `WindowsPath` refers to the actual path with TIF files.

Comment: endswith() is method of str, not of Path ..  Also, you could just use glob to get all tiff files instead of "get all files and check if they end in tiff"

Comment: Use `for im in im_path.glob('*.tif')` and the files will all be .tif files.  Also, `im.suffix` would be the extension, but no need to check if using `.glob` to begin with.

Comment: I believe the problem is that `im_path.iterdir()` returns Path objects, but `tiff2numpy()` expects plain text filenames.